# WPF-Some questions when add custom fonts as resources in my GUI

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, resources

Recently I need to realize a WPF project with a google font named Roboto.
Then I searched on the Internet to find some ways.
There were many ways to add it in my project, so I decided to try them all, especially those which was voted.
Firstly, I downloaded Toboto Font from google.
Secondly, I added a Toboto-Regular.ttf to Resources.resx, and change the Build to 'Resource'.
At last, I added some labels in a UserControl.xaml to test them.
here is the code:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="/myAPP1;component/Resources/#Roboto" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#Roboto" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="label4" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="label5" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="./Resources/#Roboto" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="label6" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" />
        <Label x:Name="label7" Content="Maintenance" FontSize="16" />
    </StackPanel>
```

label1 font was selected from Property-Text-FontFamily-Roboto, it wasn't myself coding. label2-5 were the ways I found on the internet. label6&7 were put there as contrasts.
and soon I found label1&2 were the same, label3-5 were the same, label6&7 were just what they should be.
here is the image:
[Label1-7 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtqoI.png)
then I thought what exactly the FontFamily label3-5 were? Were they Roboto-Light? so I add Roboto-Light.ttf to my resources and selected from Property again, as you can imagine, it wasn't the same like label3-5.
here is the code:

```
    <Label x:Name="label8" Content="Maintenance" FontFamily="/myAPP1;component/Resources/#Roboto Light" FontSize="16" />
```

here is the image:
[Labels with fontfamily image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ANtW.png)
To figure it out, I post the question here, waiting for your answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So label3, label4 and label5 were not working as expected ?

Comment: Exactly. Actually, I have no idea what kind of fontfamliy them are.